# Photoshop "blend modes" with OpenGL

Tags: opengl-es, webgl, photoshop, blend

I am planning to make a simple drawing tool, which supports multiple layers and all blend modes from Photoshop.

I am considering to do the blending on the GPU (put each layer into a texture and draw 2 triangles to render each layer). But I am not sure, if it is possible to implement all the [blend modes](http://www.northlite.net/ps/blend.htm) with OpenGL's blendFunc / blendEquation etc.

Another opiton is to pass all the textures + blend mode flags to one fragment shader and blend them just as I wish, but I will have to recompile FS when adding / removing some layer (sampler2D).

So what do you think? Is it possible? Are there some better ways how to use GPU for blending? Sohould I care about it now, or should I make it all on CPU and care about enhancements in the future?

BTW. it will be JavaScript program using WebGL, but I think it does not matter.

Comment: *if it is possible to implement all the blend modes with OpenGL's blendFunc / blendEquation etc.* It is not possible to implement all blend modes. Hardware framebuffer blending is somewhat limited in the operations it can perform.

Comment: Thanks Tim, I thought that some blend modes are not possible, but I was not sure. So I will just implement in on CPU.

Comment: If it helps, my open source framework here: https://github.com/BradLarson/GPUImage has many of these blend modes as OpenGL ES shaders, which should be portable to WebGL pretty easily. I used Adobe's own reference specification for the blend calculations, so these should closely match Photoshop's behavior. Just look at the top of the various blend class implementations to see the shader code I used.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Of course you can. But it need to be done in sharers.

Load two pictures (actually can be more), render triangles. But then just use your shaders to probe both textures and mix those values with equation that is dependent on current blend mode (provided as uniform).

PS do not forget to turn off mipmaps, and filtering.

Comment: Yes, I know, but there are some things I don't like about that solution. I will have to have different "sampler" for each layer. I must make new FS program when adding layers. And there may be problems when two layers have different dimensions. That's why I wanted to do it with "multiple drawings" to framebuffer.

Comment: Ok. So use multi pass solution. Instead of rendering to renderbuffer, render to texture. And when you have done it for all layers then render as normal texture. This way you need just one FS no matter how many layers.

Comment: Yes, but there is one problem - I want to be able to blend all these textures, one with another, using all blending modes from Photoshop.

Comment: Example 1: Lay A, Lay B, Lay C. Blend A with B with mode a1, than blend result with Lay C with mode a2. Or Blend A and B and C with mode b2 simultaneously?

Comment: And: So Blend(A,B,C) is not the same as Blend(A, Blend(B,C)) ? Can not first blend 2 layers, and then use result, but have to do all of them in one run?

Comment: what do you mean by "blend with mode" ? is it "blendFunc" of OpenGL, or my own mode in Fragment Shader?

Comment: No I mean mathematical operations that will describe what is happening to colors from different layers.

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/16893/discussion-between-przemo-li-and-ivan-kuckir)